# ML estimator of $\theta>0$ is $\hat{\theta}_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}$ and $I(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}$. Show $\hat{\theta}_n$ is consistent

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, convergence, consistency, fisher-information

In this problem we have that $I(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}$ is the Fisher information for a general probability density function $f(x;\theta)$ and $X_1,..., X_n$ are IID random variables from this distribution. We want to show that the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}$ is consistent.

Now we know that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}$ converges in probability to $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)$ by the weak law of large numbers. Now my problem reduces to showing that $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)=\theta$, given that the Fisher information is $I(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^2}$. I'm not too sure how to proceed with this?

Comment: The $X_{i}$ follow any particular distribution ??

Comment: Yes they are iid. It is just a general distribution. I note that the Fisher information of a Poisson$(\theta)$ random variable is $\frac{1}{\theta}$. Could this help?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to show that $\hat{\theta_{n}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}{n}$ is consistent is prove that we have the following convergence in probability

$$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}\big[\left | \hat{\theta_{n}}-\theta \right |\geq \epsilon \big]=0$$

Using the Chebyshev's Inequality we have that

$$\mathbb{P}\big[\left | \hat{\theta_{n}}-\theta \right |\geq \epsilon \big]\leq \frac{Var(\hat{\theta_{n}})}{\epsilon^{2}}$$

It is also known that asymptotically as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\hat{\theta_{n}}\Rightarrow N(\theta,I^{-1}/\sqrt{n})$, in distribution and $I$ Fisher Information.

So, I assume that by taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ in both sides you will have

$$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}\big[\left | \hat{\theta_{n}}-\theta \right |\geq \epsilon \big]\leq lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{I^{-1}}{\epsilon^{2}n^{1/2}}=0$$

Comment: Did you forget to square the $X_i$ in the sum, or did you mean to use the sum of $X_i$'s? Of course, the estimator here is the mean of $X_1^2, ..., X_n^2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right I never show that square. Let me check it again.

Comment: @user309175 I edited, you can check if you agree

Comment: Maybe I'm incorrect, but I thought that it had to be assumed that $\hat{\theta_n}$ is consistent in order for $\hat{\theta_n}$ to converge in distribution to a $N(\theta,I^{-1}/\sqrt{n})$ distribution in the first place?

Comment: As I understand it, is that the convergence in distribution, i.e in that particular Normal distribution is a MLE property. On the other hand convergence in probability admits convergence in distribution but the opposite doesn't hold. So, I assume that there might exist MLE that are not consistent but still have the convergence in distribution to that particular Normal distribution.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I'm wondering, since the Fisher information for a Poisson($\lambda$) random variable is $1/\lambda$, does this imply that the $X_i$ here are Poisson($\theta^2$) random variables, and hence their ML estimator for $\theta$ is $\sqrt{\bar{X}}$? Or does the reverse implication fail?